# Inverse Function and Integration.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, inverse-function

> Let $f$ be a continuous strictly increasing function from $[0,\infty)$ onto $[0,\infty)$ and $g=f^{-1}$ (that is, $f(x)=y$ if and only if $g(y)=x$).  Let $a,b>0$ and $a\ne b$. Then
> $$ \int_0^a f(x) dx + \int_0^b g(y) dy $$
> is
>
> (A) greater than or equal to $ab$,
> (B) less than $ab$,
> (C) always equal to $ab$,
> (D) always equal to $\frac{af(a)+bg(b)}{2}$.

Though I am done with theory part I cannot think how to approach such problems. Please give me hints on how to start solving it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This visual presentation would suffice for a multiple-choice question.  The condition holds for all $f$ that meets the condition in the problem statement.  Try to draw the conclusion.

Comment: By your graphs I can tell the Answer is Option B ( less than ab). I do not have answer key. Please tell if B is correct?

Comment: @user150700 By the way, welcome to this site.  Next time, try to use the [markup](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) and [math code](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/32803) of this website to post questions.  That way, others are more likely to help you out.

Comment: @user150700 In your original comment, you mentioned that Option A is correct.  The answer is A.  What prompts you to think that B is correct?

Comment: @FrenzyLi I changed because in graph is Integration of f and g will give shaded areas which is less than ab

Comment: @user150700 No... the converse is true. Notice that the sum of the integration contains an extra part (in dashed circle, under the arrow with "vanishes iff ...") than the rectangle.

Comment: @FrenzyLi okay. Now what I am getting is. for integration of f differential strip runs from 0 to a in horizontal. For g differential strip runs is vertical direction covering common area. Total area = extra area in f + 2 × common area + extra area in g?

Comment: @user150700 The common area is 0. The two shaded parts A and C do not overlap.  The reason is, $f$ is an inverse function of $g$ and vice versa.

Comment: I am posting some pictures. Please see.

Comment: Sorry. It is not allowing me to post picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ7V1.jpg please see the link

Comment: @user150700 Second image is incorrect.  $\int_0^b g(y) dy = \int_0^b g(\color{blue}{x}) d\color{blue}{x}$

Comment: @FrenzyLi Thank you. I understood now.